# Why useEffect is not called when I get a null value response from the api?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What im tryin to do is to get data from the backend. To do that I'm using `axios.get()`.
I have created an useEffect without a dependency, because I want to call it every time.
The useEffect works, but when I get a null value as a response it stops, and if I add a new value (from postman) to test if the list will be updated but it won't. Only if I refresh the screen it will start getting the data list every second.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('called');
    axios
      .get(`API`)
      .then((response) => {
        setDataList(response.data.data); //null or data
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
  });
```

How can I make the useEffect work even when I get a null value from response ?

Comment: null.data will produce an exception, right?

Answer (score 0):

By not putting a dependency array in place, you get the same effect as not using `useEffect` in the first place.

Every time the component renders, the Ajax request is triggered.

Your problem is that, all else being equal, the only time it will re-render is if `setDataList(response.data.data)` sets a **different value**.

If it errors, then it isn't setting **any** value so it won't trigger a re-render.

---

You need to decide what you really want to trigger a new request. For example, a timer.

(Untested code);

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timeOut = null;
    let controller = null;
    const makeRequest = async () => {
        controller = new AbortController();
        const response = await axios.get(`API`, {
            signal: controller.signal
        });
        const data = response.data?.data;
        if (data) setDataList(data);
        setTimeout(makeRequest, 5000); // Wait 5 seconds then poll again
    };
    makeRequest(); // Start the timer.
    // Clean up on unmount
    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        controller.abort();
    };
}, [ /* You need a dependency array to stop multiple timers being created! */ ]);
```